# Shallow Copy of Instance of Class within an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have an ArrayList which contains n instances of the class Boat. The class Boat has a number of methods which alter the instance variables of that boat.

For example:

```
public void Command(String command)
{
    int inefficientwayofdoingthis=0;
    if(command.equals("power on"))
    {
        inefficientwayofdoingthis++;
        int x=1;
        setpower(x);
        System.out.println(name+" is on and is travelling in the direction of "+angle+" deg. with speed: "+ speed+"mph");
    }
    //...
```

The issue I am having is that this Command method should set the value of `[instancename].power` to 1.

The instances are contained in an ArrayList, data:

I am using  the following code to alter the instances within the arraylist:

```
int numberinArray = whatever;
String theorder = "power on";
data.get(numberinArray).Command(theorder);
```

Each time I do so however, the command works and an output is produced, but subsequent commands do not seem to recognize that `data.get(numberinArray).power` should equal 1. I think I'm having a problem in that this is a deep copy of each instance of the class rather than a shallow copy. Would anyone have any suggestions on how to alleviate this issue?

Comment: what is this set power button doing. can you post that method?

Comment: Sorry thats antiquated - an attempt to find the problem. It should be power=1;

Comment: @Danlvvy sorry your last comment didn't make any sense.

Comment: "I think I'm having a problem in that this is a deep copy of each instance of the class rather than a shallow copy." In that case, please show the code that performs the copy.

Comment: I tried to go as shallow as possible with this:

Boat temporary = createcopy(data.get(numberinArray));

public static Boat createcopy(Boat a)
    {
        Boat copy = new Boat("");
        copy.angle=a.angle;
        copy.name=a.name;
        copy.speed=a.speed;
        copy.power=a.power;
        return copy;
    }

Comment: Al @FarazDurrani i meant that setpower(1); should not be there, it should read "data.get(numberinArray).power=1"

Comment: Unrelated : read about Java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase. All lower case is super hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the power stay "attached" to the boat instance, this should be an instance variable. This could work in a way like this:

```
package com;

public class Boat {

    private int power;
    private String color;

    Boat() {
        // may want to initialize some values
        this.setPower(0);
        this.setColor("red");
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

then you could add some other methods like `applyCommand(String command)` in your example